What is wrong with my 3 avocado trees?
I purchased 3 grafted avocado trees (different varieties) and planted them a few months ago. They were doing pretty good until recently when the leaves on all 3 trees started to change color and look pathetic. I am including a picture of the tree. Please let me know what I should do to save them. I am south of Athens, Greece. The planting zone is very similar to Los Angeles. [![avocado1[Thanks

Planted them in what? If soil mixture from the store, the packaging should say. Not that I can answer but I suspect it could help. Timeline of the browning? As to decide if it was improper replanting. Light exposure - direct and indirect sun per day?

planted in the ground using store bought potting soil. Over the course of about three months the leaves started browning from the bottom of the trunk and slowly upwards. I water regularly and it has sun exposure for at least 8 hours.
